# Set Component props on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button that references to a specific data, then I want to add a component with a props specific to the data that is referenced to that button.

```
<MyComponent v-bind:props="mydata[0]"/>
```

that is basically what I'm doing, let say I want to bind a props `mydata[1]` instead of `mydata[2]` without typing it manually on the template, I want the props to be dynamic. thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to send data to the appropriate component you can use `watch` with `this.$route` and in your App.vue file add method to send data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a variable called **index** in data, and change that variable on that button click to the specific index, something like this

```
<v-btn @click="index = 1">display data of 1</v-btn>
```

and

```
<MyComponent v-bind:props="mydata[index]"/>
```

Comment: I thought once I using a component is like append() in jquery so I didn't know props could be dynamic. Thanks, vue js is awesome